# auto-generate jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, database, tabs

After trying several options (jQuery UI tabs & jQuery Tools tabs) and not getting the correct results from either one... here I am again.

What I want to do:

Dynamically generate the entire tab structure on page load. Data to be used to build the tabs is in a mySql database, being retrieved via getJSON().

I tend to get ALL my data returned and it appears to be placed in the correct DOM location (ie. inside my 'tabs' DIV), but when I call ("#tabs").tabs(); function, the tabs do not show up correctly.

I can provide code, but would like to see what other suggest. Anyone encounter an issue with dynamically generating the entire tab structure? Anyone get it to work correctly?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

---

Ok, here is the code I am using to create the tabs, I have posted this before, but as I stated in the original, I want to see if anyone else has done a dynamic creation of the entire tab structure...

Using this, I get all the 'tabs' stacked vertically, with all the 'panes' underneath that, again stacked vertically.

```
var stateData;

$.getJSON("getStateData.php", function(data) {
    stateData = data;
    var $theLastGroup = "zzzzz";
    var $ulItems = "<ul class='groupTabs'>\n";
    var $divItems = "";

    $.each(stateData, function(i,jsonData) {

        if( $theLastGroup != jsonData.groupName )
        {
            $ulItems = $ulItems+"<li><a href='#"+jsonData.groupName+"'>"+jsonData.groupID+"</a></li>\n";

            if( i > 0 ) 
            {
                $divItems = $divItems+"</div>\n";           
            }
            $divItems = $divItems+"<div id='"+jsonData.groupName+"'>\n";

            $theLastGroup = jsonData.groupName;
        }

        $divItems = $divItems+"<span sname='"+jsonData.stateName+
            "' lat='"+jsonData.centerLat+
            "' lon='"+jsonData.centerLon+
            "' zom='"+jsonData.zoom+"' >"+jsonData.stateName+"</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";

    });
    $ulItems = $ulItems+"</ul>\n";
    $divItems = $divItems+"</div>\n";


    $("#tabs").append($ulItems);
    $("#tabs").append($divItems);

    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

---

05-20-2011 - ANYONE have any more thoughts on this? I was missing the final `</div>`, but that did not make a difference....(i added the code above).

Comment: Should show your code and what isn't displaying correctly.

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing your code. Are you waiting to call the jquery after all the tabs have been completed. If you are getting the data using ajax, you would have to do the call in the success of the ajax call after you have added the tabs. If you are calling the jquery in the pageLoad after the function to create the tabs the ajax to get data may not return before the jquery is run.

Comment: Has your CSS been setup properly? The CSS classes are what handle where the elements show on the page. The jquery just adds the class for it to use.

Comment: I have this in the HTML Head: `code`<link href="js_src/css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.js"></script>`code`

Comment: Are all class names linking properly? Have any class names you have been changed in code have also been changed in the CSS file? Also are you positive the CSS is actually loading? I am not doubting you are doing it correctly.

Comment: @jmein: I DO get what appears to be correct CSS, that is, the Cupertino effect is applied to the 'tabs' portion.

Comment: Your ul has a class of groupTabs instead of tabs. Has that been changed in the CSS? Now that may be the current default class for the tabs, I am going off of the version we are using currently.

Comment: @jmein: You mean the UL 'has' to have a class of "tabs"??? I did not see that in any of the examples or documentation. One of my previous attempts did not have any class for the UL.

Comment: In the version I am using, the ul has a class of tabs and the div that contains all panes has a class of panes. However, your version may be newer and they may have changed things.

Comment: Be sure you are getting both start and end `<div></div>`.  `alert($divItems)` if you have to.  I am not sure will get and end div.

Comment: Could you give us a link to the demos you are looking at?

Comment: The demos are just the ones on the jQuery UI site: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: @Blazes: You are wanting to see the <div></div> around which part? The 'existing' HTML is: `code`<div style="height:100px" id="tabs" class="hidden"> <h4>State Groups Test</h4> <h5>select a state to see available races...</h5> </div>`code`

Comment: @all: I do have some 'minor' CSS in the <head>: 
`code`<style type="text/css">
    div.hidden {display:none;}
    li.hidden {display:none;}
    span.hidden {display:none;}
    ul.hidden {display:none;}
</style>`code`
Do you think this could be causing an issue?

Comment: Well, the extra CSS as noted above does not make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken, your problem is the alignment of the tabs generated by your code.

and if thats the real problem. try to code a simple unordered list css tags for the class that you have used in your code.

like this..

```
ul.groupTabs li{float:left; padding 10px; display:block;}
```

hope this help you...

~gio